# Send JSON string to the server and receive JSON string from the server

Tags: java, json

I would like to be able to send a JSON string to a server, then let the server process the string and give me a proper response all using Java.
Here's an example:

```
{
    "requestType": "SomeType"
    "name": "Steve"
    "age": 37
}
```

Then the server would then give a proper response.

```
{
    "reponseType": "Ok"
}
```

Should this be done through an HTTP request or something else and if so, how would I go about this?

Comment: If you're new to Java Web programming, definitely don't go low-level with servlets. Use Spring MVC or Dropwizard.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't really had the need to use java for web programming until now, seems like I'll have to read up on quite some stuff tomorrow. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this would be done through an HTTP request. Based on your question containing a Java tag, I would suggest you look into Java Servlets/JSPs and research a server that implements the Servlet/JSP specs (e.g., Apache Tomcat). The following site is a good reference for learning about these topics: [Core Servlets](http://www.coreservlets.com/)

Comment: Thanks you, I believe this is what I need.